# ffmpeg - video from images - stops before last frame

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to create videos from images. Although I have done this many times, I see now that a certain video stops before the last frame, encoding only ~50% of it.

The way I call ffmpeg is

```
ffmpeg -y -threads 16 -r 30 -i /tmp/teaser/SINGLE/%*_2_.png -vcodec h264  -vf scale=2000:-2 -an -b:v 5000k /tmp/teaser_SINGLE_2_.mp4
```

The output is:

```
Output #0, mp4, to     '/tmp/teaser_SINGLE_2_.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.41.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv444p, 2000x1316, q=-1--1, 5000 kb/s, 30 fps, 15360 tbn, 30 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.48.101 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/5000000 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (png (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Input stream #0:0 frame changed from size:2000x1315 fmt:rgba to size:2000x1315 fmt:pal8
Input stream #0:0 frame changed from size:2000x1315 fmt:pal8 to size:2000x1315 fmt:rgba
Input stream #0:0 frame changed from size:2000x1315 fmt:rgba to size:2000x1315 fmt:pal8 drop=6 speed=0.0278x    x
Input stream #0:0 frame changed from size:2000x1315 fmt:pal8 to size:2000x1315 fmt:rgba
Input stream #0:0 frame changed from size:2000x1315 fmt:rgba to size:2000x1315 fmt:pal8 drop=16 speed=0.0237x
Input stream #0:0 frame changed from size:2000x1315 fmt:pal8 to size:2000x1315 fmt:rgba
Input stream #0:0 frame changed from size:2000x1315 fmt:rgba to size:2000x1315 fmt:pal8 drop=23 speed=0.022x
Input stream #0:0 frame changed from size:2000x1315 fmt:pal8 to size:2000x1315 fmt:rgba
Input stream #0:0 frame changed from size:2000x1315 fmt:rgba to size:2000x1315 fmt:pal8
Input stream #0:0 frame changed from size:2000x1315 fmt:pal8 to size:2000x1315 fmt:rgba drop=30 speed=0.0206x
Input stream #0:0 frame changed from size:2000x1315 fmt:rgba to size:2000x1315 fmt:pal8
Input stream #0:0 frame changed from size:2000x1315 fmt:pal8 to size:2000x1315 fmt:rgba
Input stream #0:0 frame changed from size:2000x1315 fmt:rgba to size:2000x1315 fmt:pal8
Input stream #0:0 frame changed from size:2000x1315 fmt:pal8 to size:2000x1315 fmt:rgba drop=47 speed=0.0172x
Input stream #0:0 frame changed from size:2000x1315 fmt:rgba to size:2000x1315 fmt:pal8
Input stream #0:0 frame changed from size:2000x1315 fmt:pal8 to size:2000x1315 fmt:rgba drop=54 speed=0.0163x
Input stream #0:0 frame changed from size:2000x1315 fmt:rgba to size:2000x1315 fmt:pal8
Input stream #0:0 frame changed from size:2000x1315 fmt:pal8 to size:2000x1315 fmt:rgba
Input stream #0:0 frame changed from size:2000x1315 fmt:rgba to size:2000x1315 fmt:pal8 drop=59 speed=0.0155x
Input stream #0:0 frame changed from size:2000x1315 fmt:pal8 to size:2000x1315 fmt:rgba
Input stream #0:0 frame changed from size:2000x1315 fmt:rgba to size:2000x1315 fmt:pal8
Input stream #0:0 frame changed from size:2000x1315 fmt:pal8 to size:2000x1315 fmt:rgba drop=65 speed=0.0148x
Input stream #0:0 frame changed from size:2000x1315 fmt:rgba to size:2000x1315 fmt:pal8
Input stream #0:0 frame changed from size:2000x1315 fmt:pal8 to size:2000x1315 fmt:rgba
Input stream #0:0 frame changed from size:2000x1315 fmt:rgba to size:2000x1315 fmt:pal8 drop=71 speed=0.0141x
Input stream #0:0 frame changed from size:2000x1315 fmt:pal8 to size:2000x1315 fmt:rgba
Input stream #0:0 frame changed from size:2000x1315 fmt:rgba to size:2000x1315 fmt:pal8 drop=77 speed=0.0135x
Input stream #0:0 frame changed from size:2000x1315 fmt:pal8 to size:2000x1315 fmt:rgba
Input stream #0:0 frame changed from size:2000x1315 fmt:rgba to size:2000x1315 fmt:pal8
Input stream #0:0 frame changed from size:2000x1315 fmt:pal8 to size:2000x1315 fmt:rgba
Input stream #0:0 frame changed from size:2000x1315 fmt:rgba to size:2000x1315 fmt:pal8 drop=90 speed=0.0124x
Input stream #0:0 frame changed from size:2000x1315 fmt:pal8 to size:2000x1315 fmt:rgba
Input stream #0:0 frame changed from size:2000x1315 fmt:rgba to size:2000x1315 fmt:pal8 drop=148 speed=0.00909x
Input stream #0:0 frame changed from size:2000x1315 fmt:pal8 to size:2000x1315 fmt:rgba
Input stream #0:0 frame changed from size:2000x1315 fmt:rgba to size:2000x1315 fmt:pal8 drop=179 speed=0.00786x
Input stream #0:0 frame changed from size:2000x1315 fmt:pal8 to size:2000x1315 fmt:rgba
Input stream #0:0 frame changed from size:2000x1315 fmt:rgba to size:2000x1315 fmt:pal8 drop=184 speed=0.00765x
Input stream #0:0 frame changed from size:2000x1315 fmt:pal8 to size:2000x1315 fmt:rgba
frame=   64 fps=2.6 q=-1.0 Lsize=     822kB time=00:00:02.03 bitrate=3310.7kbits/s dup=0 drop=209 speed=0.0822x
video:820kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.190141%
[libx264 @ 0x7feb45023a00] frame I:1     Avg QP:13.80  size:  6902
[libx264 @ 0x7feb45023a00] frame P:16    Avg QP: 4.91  size: 20914
[libx264 @ 0x7feb45023a00] frame B:47    Avg QP: 9.96  size: 10589
[libx264 @ 0x7feb45023a00] consecutive B-frames:  1.6%  0.0%  4.7% 93.8%
[libx264 @ 0x7feb45023a00] mb I  I16..4:  0.2% 98.3%  1.6%
[libx264 @ 0x7feb45023a00] mb P  I16..4:  0.1%  0.1%  0.5%  P16..4:  0.3%  0.6%  0.6%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:97.8%
[libx264 @ 0x7feb45023a00] mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  B16..8:  0.6%  0.6%  0.6%  direct: 0.2%  skip:98.0%  L0:35.6% L1:34.8% BI:29.7%
[libx264 @ 0x7feb45023a00] final ratefactor: 0.46
[libx264 @ 0x7feb45023a00] 8x8 transform intra:87.7% inter:9.6%
[libx264 @ 0x7feb45023a00] coded y,u,v intra: 9.6% 6.6% 8.9% inter: 1.2% 0.4% 0.8%
[libx264 @ 0x7feb45023a00] i16 v,h,dc,p: 83% 10%  6%  1%
[libx264 @ 0x7feb45023a00] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 29%  1% 70%  0%  0%  0%  0%  0%  0%
[libx264 @ 0x7feb45023a00] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 38% 11% 14%  5%  5%  8%  5% 10%  5%
[libx264 @ 0x7feb45023a00] Weighted P-Frames: Y:6.2% UV:6.2%
[libx264 @ 0x7feb45023a00] ref P L0: 53.5% 16.5% 18.2% 11.2%  0.6%
[libx264 @ 0x7feb45023a00] ref B L0: 86.6% 10.8%  2.7%
[libx264 @ 0x7feb45023a00] ref B L1: 93.8%  6.2%
[libx264 @ 0x7feb45023a00] kb/s:3147.04
```

There doesn't seem to be any destroyed frame. Any idea?

I use `ffmpeg version 3.1.4`

Comment: Has to do something with naming. Try renaming it a numeric sequence. Also, use `-framerate 30` instead of `-r 30`.

Comment: Just the `-framerate 30` did the job!!!!! But I don't understand why. If you want please post this as an answer so that I can mark this as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With image sequences, you have to use the framerate option. With -r specified before the sequence name, FFmpeg assumes 25 fps and duplicates/drop frames to meet the set rate. I'm guessing you had a very short sequence, so it wasn't readily apparent.